# Laravel won't send mail with 25 port and no encryption

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-mail

I have a problem with laravel and sending emails within local network where it is used 25 port without encryption.

When I send mail only I can get is failure that contains emails array.

Nothing comes within logs, I am even using telescope and nothing pops up on telescope not even on requests tab.

When I change mail settings to other mail server and port 465 with ssl or 587 tls it works. I get request on telescope page for requests, I get that mail is sent and I get mail.

Comment: What mail service are you using?

Comment: Something I pulled from Google, unsure its relevance: '*Many email clients and services use port 25 for SMTP to send out emails. However an ISP (Internet Service Provider) may block port 25 in order to prevent spamming by its customers*'

Comment: It seems when I use phpmailer it works, but with built in mail in laravel it does not.

Comment: Try using some service like Sendgrid.

Comment: I just tried with mailtrap with port 25 and no encryption and it does work

Comment: This sounds like it's going to be an issue with the port. You'll need to make sure you're using the correct port for the provider you're using.